# How do I batch convert .odt files to .docx files?

Tags: microsoft-word, batch, libreoffice, docx, odt

At the moment I have a large collection of .odt files and I want to batch convert them to .docx files. I am working on a windows 10 computer. There are several options recommended on the web, almost all from the period 2008-2010 and none seem to work.

Rest of the post is options I tried:

One option is using the commandline and libreoffice. Something like this should work:
soffice --headless --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" test.docx
Or this:
start /wait "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.exe" --headless --convert-to docx --outdir D:\sourcePath\testFile.odt
However both commands and several variations I tried did nothing. No error, no new files, just nothing.

Another recommended option is BatchConv (http://oooconv.free.fr/batchconv/batchconv_en.html), in conjunction with open office. This also did nothing. I opened the file, accepted the macro's on start up, clicked the button, selected the files in the wizard, open office flickered for a while and in the end no files were converted and no error was shown.

Lastly an recommende option was mso2ooo, however this doesn't support docx (only doc).

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best

- run scalc from Open Office.
- File> Wizard > Document Converter
- StarOffice - text documents > NEXT
- disable templates unless used.
- include subdirectories and select FROM , TO
- CONVERT

then use MSOffice to convert DOC to Docx

Comment: Do you mean open office calc? (At this point I have gotten rather paranoid about what is a typo and what is me missing something). 
I tried this method in calc and it couldn't find any documents. 0 documents found, 0 converted.

Comment: yes OO calc is scalc.exe  < Sorry I guess it is intended for other open text doc formats other than Open Doc *.odt